# Ellipsize middle of string in Javascriptt

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, function, ecmascript-6

I am currently trying to create a function that will ellipsize the middle of a text string. The idea is for it to show the first five characters and the last five characters. The middle of the string will just show as

> ...

So for example if I have dkjkjfdljfldkjfssdfsf

It should show as

> dkjkj...sdfsf

I so far have this function:

function ellipsizeIt(text, length) {
if (text.length > length) { return `${text.substring(0, length)}...${text.substring(0, length)}`; }
return text;
}

But its just repeating the string first five characters when I do:

```
ellipsizeIt(text, 5);
```

It will show as

> dkjkj...dkjkj

Any way to do it so that it doesnt just repeat the first five characters in the end of the string and show the actual last 5 characters?

Comment: What if the length of the string is odd?

Comment: `myString.substring(myString.length  - 5)` seems to get the last 5 characters from a string

Comment: odd or even is fine

Comment: If the string length is odd, say, 11 chars, would you ellipsize after the 5th character, after the 6th character, or replace the 6th character?

Answer (score 1):

From the code above there is a typo/logic issue where you had `${text.substring(0, length)}...${text.substring(0,length)}`;.

You are repeating yourself, so is the code.

update your code to

```js
function ellipsizeIt(text, length) {
  if (text.length > length) {
    return `${text.substring(0, length)}...${text.substring(text.length -length)}`; 
  }
}
```